# Unable to initialize a RecyclerView: null object reference

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter, nestedrecyclerview

When setting my `RecyclerView`'s `layoutManager` and `adpater`, I am getting this error:

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
```

Here's a snippet of my custom `RecyclerView.Adapter`. I want to put a nested `RecyclerView` where it is not scrollable, and the size is according to the elements inside it. The context is set when creating the ViewHolder, which I need to pass it to my inner RecyclerView.

```
//...

private lateinit var context: Context

override fun onCreateViewHolder(
    parent: ViewGroup,
    viewType: Int
): ViewHolder {
    context = parent.context
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        .inflate(R.layout.date_card, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount() = data.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val dateItem = data[position]
    with(holder.itemView) {
        tv_day.text = dateItem.getDayOfMonth()
        tv_day2.text = dateItem.getDayName(resources)
        rv_overview.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@DateAdapter.context)
            adapter = PlanAdapter(dateItem.planItems)
            setHasFixedSize(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Can you include your `ViewHolder` and the layout?

Comment: Your `RecyclerView` is null as the error states, the adapter, for this problem, is irrelevant

Comment: Please post the recyclerView instantiation code.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I fixed it! Turns out the nested recyclerview did not have an id. Once I set the id and referenced that, the code is working.